# Elasticsearch heap getting filled for simple search

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, heap-memory

Executed the following simple search request:
`http://localhost:9200/_search?size=100000`

My heap usage suddenly getting increased. Since the query doesn't contain any filter fields , aggregations, etc. there are no chances for field data cache and filtered cache to fill the heap. I don't understand what are the reasons behind heap usage increase.

I am suspecting it is because of `_source` field of documents. But I am not sure. I would like to know what is happening behind scenes.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's because `size=100000`. Elasticsearch will allocate memory for that number of documents to store as a result. And 100000 is a big number. If you lower that to 1000, for example, probably you will not fill the heap so much.

In any case, using `size=100000` is a strong no-no. Don't do that. This is not how Elasticsearch is supposed to work. Elasticsearch will give you back results in a [paginated way](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html), page by page. Or use [scan&scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scan-scroll.html). In any case, never do `size=LARGE_NUMBER`. For a high enough number you can bring down the cluster, by making each node run out of memory and throw `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: Can you try to issue the same request with fields=(only one of known fields)

Comment: Specifying "fields" or "_source" won't help with memory usage since the entire document is still loaded in memory before reducing to the requested response. Your reduce wire size but not heap size. I second the size=100000 no-no. Paginate or scan&scroll.